# "file system simulation implementation"

Tags: c#, file, system, simulation

I am working with a group and we need to design and program a file system simulation program in C#.
i did a lot of research and i think i understand the basics of file systems and what kind of data structures i need to use and also the space allocation algorithms and data structures to use. As I said it should be a very simple system and i am thinking about using a tree for the data structure of the Files and use a linked list for the space allocation.
My question is how to implement all of this? i know this a broad question so i will be specific.
For the files I am thinking about creating a class :
here's an example:

```
class File 
{
    private string Name;
    private string type;
    private DateTime DateOfCreation;
    private double size;
    private int Datalink;
    private string content;

    public File(
        string fileName,
        string fileType,
        DateTime dateofCreation,
        double filesize,
        int fileDataLink,
        string fileContent
        )
    {
        this.Name = fileName;
        this.size = filesize;
        this.DateOfCreation = dateofCreation;
        this.Datalink = fileDataLink;
        this.content = fileContent;
        this.type = fileType;

    }
    public File()
    {
    }
    public string get_Name()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}
```

And i created the sets and gets.

My question is : how to create multiple instances of this class and get them indexed (By name for instance) just like databases records?

I might be thinking outside the box and i need to use different data structures(HashTable or Dictionary)

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

You need of a root node (object) and from that move to the selected node.